# Conic section circle question

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have problem in solving this envelope question from degrande relations book. It's from part B of question parts. It says

> The middle point of a chord of a circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$  is on a fixed line with equation $x=a$. Find the equation of envelope of such chords.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Tried to find a equation of line and then setting delta in quadratic formula equal to zero .

Comment: See here how to obtain the equation of the envelope of a family of lines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)